# Cannot draw pixels on Y-axis with INT 10h / AH = 0Ch

Tags: assembly, graphics, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I have the following code fragment which should draw a diagonal starting from (30, 100), however, it simply paints a horizontal line on top of the screen, like this:

[image]

To test the code, I run `make run`.

This is `loader.asm`:

```
    BITS 16

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------

_start:
    mov ax, 07C0h
    add ax, 288
    mov ss, ax              ; ss = stack space
    mov sp, 4096            ; sp = stack pointer

    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax              ; ds = data segment

    call print_pixel

    jmp $                   ; infinite loop

; ----------------------------------------------------------------------

print_pixel:

    ; changing video mode to graphical

    mov ah, 00h             ; set video mode

    mov al, 13h             ; 13h - graphical mode.
                            ; 40x25. 256 colors.;320x200 pixels. 1 page.

    int 10h                 ; call

    ; drawing random pixels

    mov ah, 0Ch             ; change color for a single pixel

    mov al, 0000b           ; color
    mov bh, 0               ; page number
    mov cx, 30              ; x
    mov dx, 100             ; y

    int 10h                 ; paint 1st pixel

.repeat:

    inc al                  ; change color
    inc cx                  ; go one pixel right
    inc dx                  ; go one pixel down

    int 10h                 ; paint

    cmp al, 1111b
    je .done                ; last color was painted

    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ; padding with 0 at the end
dw 0xAA55                   ; PC boot signature
```

This is `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: build run

build: image.flp

run: build
    qemu-system-i386 -fda image.flp

image.bin: loader.asm
    nasm -f bin -o image.bin loader.asm

image.flp: image.bin
    dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=image.bin of=image.flp
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the horizontal line. Works fine for me.

Comment: @cad are you using my Makefile and `make run`?

Comment: Yup, just the same. It's on ArchLinux, Linux 4.1.6, 64 bit.

Comment: Maybe you should test it on another emulator like bochs.

Comment: @cad I am running Ubuntu 15.04, Linux 3.19, 64 bit. I would try `bochs` but it seems more difficult to setup and I didn't find any guide to get it running. I would like to continue using `qemu`. I believe that using another `-display` might fix my issue, but `-display gtk`, which seems the best option, was disabled.

Comment: @cad I setup bochs. Not that difficult after all. Thank you!

Comment: Works fine here: Debian Wheezy (Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 x86_64), QEMU emulator version 1.1.2 (Debian 1.1.2+dfsg-6a+deb7u11).

Comment: @rkhb Thanks for checking! I still don't know why it isn't working for me, but I started using bochs. My version is `QEMU emulator version 2.2.0 (Debian 1:2.2+dfsg-5expubuntu9.5)`.

Comment: @rkhb pursuant to my answer, I'd be curious if you observe this bug on your Debian Wheezy system if you run it with `qemu-system-i386 -fda image.flp -vga std` . I don't have a Wheezy system handy to try it out.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Just tried with the additional parameter: no problem. I don't know which std-VGA I have. I did install QEMU just with `aptitude install qemu`.

Comment: @rkhb Thanks, I only asked to see if this issue might have been some kind of regression in latest Debian systems. If it works in Wheezy, this issue may have crept in between then and now.

Comment: I would try to use direct memory access `[0xA000:(x+320*y)]=color` if not protected

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have stumbled on a bug with the default *Plex86 VGA BIOS* that QEMU is using on our version of Ubuntu. it could be a bug in the Plex86 VGA code; a bug between the SeaBIOS and Plex86; could have been some problem with the options used by the Ubuntu/Debian team to build that BIOS. You can probably try using the *Cirrus VGA BIOS* by modifying your `Makefile` so that this line:

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda image.flp
```

is changed to:

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda image.flp -vga cirrus
```

I happened to run your code on Ubuntu 15.04 and had similar behavior. It appears that the contents of the *DX* register are not honored (which contains the Y axis value).

Although not part of your problem in this case - when using `int 10h` you shouldn't assume the *AX*/*AH*/*AL* register will be preserved. There are some older VGA BIOSes that may clobber it.

I've also discovered on my Debian Jessie system where your code originally worked, that it fails if I specifically use the *Plex86 VGA BIOS* by running with this command:

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda image.flp -vga std
```

It appears this issue isn't specific to Ubuntu. It affects Debian as well. it seems that Debian may default to a different VGA BIOS when none is specified.